# ¿Cómo sustituir un valor en un data.frame?

Tags: r, funciones, bucles, dataframe

Mi error empieza al iniciar el primer loop, donde no me deja sustituir un valor de un data.frame por otro valor (factor). Encima sale que hay un error en una condición y no sé por qué. Cuando prueben el código, verán que sale: 
Error in if (Playersmatrix[b, 1] == Emptyspace[1]) { : 
  valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
Además: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Nunca había programado en mi vida. Muchas gracias.

```
numberSymbols<-function(symbols)
  {
    symbols=readline(prompt="How many consecutive symbols are required to win? ")
   if((symbols=="1")|(symbols=="2")|(symbols=="3")|(symbols=="4")|(symbols=="5")|(symbols=="6")|(symbols=="7")|(symbols=="8")|(symbols=="9")|(symbols=="10"))  cat (" ")
  else
     {
      print("Number of symbols incorrect")
      numberSymbols(symbols)
     }
symbols=as.integer(symbols)
return(symbols)
}

Option1<-function(askData)
{
Playersmatrix1=matrix("_",10,1)
Playersmatrix2=matrix(0,10,2)
Playersmatrix=data.frame(Playersmatrix1,Playersmatrix2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(Playersmatrix)=c("Names","Games","Points")

cat("Who are going to play? ")
Player1=readline(prompt="Who is the first player? ")
Player2=readline(prompt="Who is the second player? ")

symbols=numberSymbols(symbols)



print(Playersmatrix)

b=1
repeat
{
if(Playersmatrix[b,1]=="_"){Playersmatrix[b,1]=Player1; b=nrow(Playersmatrix)}
else { if(Playersmatrix[b,1]==Player1)  
    {answer=readline(prompt="This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name? ") 
    if((answer=="Yes")|(answer=="yes")) 
        {Player1=readline(prompt="Write a new name, please "); Player1=as.factor(Player1); Playersmatrix[b,1]=Player1; b=nrow(Playersmatrix)} else cat (" ")} else {cat (" ") }}
b=b+1   
if(b==nrow(Playersmatrix)+1) break
 } 

b=1
repeat
{
if (Playersmatrix[b,1]=="_"){Playersmatrix[b,1]=Player2; b=nrow(Playersmatrix)}
else { if(Playersmatrix[b,1]==Player2) 
    {answer=readline(prompt="This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name? ") 
    if((answer=="Yes")|(answer=="yes")) 
        {Player2=readline(prompt="Write a new name, please ");  Player2=as.factor(Player2); Playersmatrix[b,1]=Player2; b=nrow(Playersmatrix)} else cat (" ")} else{ cat (" ") }}

b=b+1   
if(b==nrow(Playersmatrix)+1) break
 } 

print(Playersmatrix)
return(list(symbols, Player1, Player2))
}
Option1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin saber exactamente que hace el código, puedo decirte que tienes algunos problemas.

1. En varios lugres, estás haciendo `b=11` con la idea de salir según entiendo, sin embargo en el final del `repeat` haces `b=b+1;if(b==11) break` de forma que cuando hay que salir, `b` se incrementa y vale 12, por lo que nunca saldrás del ciclo. Entiendo que te alcanzaría con salir en cada caso con un `break` explícito en vez del `b=11`.
2. Tienes un problema por el hecho de trabajar con factores, a los que por otro lado no le veo sentido en este caso. Los factores no con variables comunes a las que puedes reemplazar valores, por ejemplo:

   ```
   df <- data.frame(b=as.factor(c("S", "N")))
   df[1,1] <- as.factor("Otra cosa")

   Warning message:
   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1L) :
     invalid factor level, NA generated

   df

        b
   1 <NA>
   2    N
   ```

   Un factor es un objeto que tiene un conjunto de datos categóricos, puedes modificar un dato en particular de una columna, pero por alguno de las categorías de dicho factor, pero no por las categorías de otro factor totalmente distinto. Creo que la confusión viene del comportamiento por defecto de `data.frame()` que trata cualquier cadena como `factor`. Para evitar esto, puedes crear `Playersmatrix` así:

   ```
   Playersmatrix=data.frame(Playersmatrix1,Playersmatrix2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   ```

   y también deja de convertir los datos a `factor` por ejemplo en:

   ```
   Player1=as.factor(Player1)
   Emptyspace=as.factor(Emptyspace)
   ```